# Where are all the bobble heads?

Tags: fallout-4

Where are the locations of all the bobble heads?  I'm assuming there's 1 per stat just like in fallout 3?  Or are there multiples this time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I checked 3 different sites and they all had these listed.
Bobble-head Locations

- **Agility** -- Wreckage of the FMS Northern Star Located on a wooden platform justpast the deck huts near the very edge of the ship's bow.
- **Barter** -- Longneck Lukowski’s Cannery     In an upper area of the main cannery room, look in the metal catwalk hut.
- **Big Guns** -- Vault 95  On top of a radio in the northernmost room of the living quarters.
- **Charisma** -- Parsons State Insane Asylum   On Jack Cabot's desk inside his office in the Administration area.
- **Endurance** -- Poseidon Energy Within the central metal catwalk hut, find the Bobblehead on the metal desk near a magazine.
- **Energy Weapons** -- Fort Hagen Found on a small table between two fridges in the southwest kitchens of the Command Center.
- **Explosives** -- Saugus Ironworks On the catwalk in the Blast Furnace area, near a magazine and steamer trunk.
- **Intelligence** -- Boston Public Library Found in the northwest corner of the library, in the mechanical room near the computers.
- **Lock Picking** -- Pickman Gallery In the final tunnel chamber where you meet Pickman, find the Bobblehead on the ground between the brick pillars.
- **Luck** -- Spectacle Island Inside a locker next to the steamer trunk, on the green boat to the south of the island.
- **Medicine** -- Vault 81 Found in Curie's office, in the southeast corner of secret Vault 81.
- **Melee** -- Trinity Tower Head to the very top of Trinity Tower to find the Bobblehead within the cage where Rex and Strong are held.
- **Perception** -- Museum of Freedom Found upon a metal desk inside the room where you meet Preston Garvey and the others.
- **Repair** -- Corvega Assemply Plant On the southwest roof section of the plant, locate this Bobblehead at the very end of the overhead exterior structure.
- **Science** -- Malden Middle School (Vault 75) Within the vault building, head to Basement level 3 and locate the collectibel on a desk overlooking the Diner area.
- **Small Guns** -- Gunners Plaza Found upon the broadcast desk within the on-air room on the ground floor of the building.
- **Sneak** -- Dunwich Borers Locate this Bobblehead on top of a small metal table next to a lantern beside the metal post terminal.
- **Speech** -- Park Street Station (Vault 114)     Found inside the Overseer's office where Nick Valentine is being held.
- **Strength** -- Mass Fusion Building  Find this Bobblehead on top of the high metal wall statue above the lobby desk.
- **Unarmed** -- Atom Cats Garage Located on top the hood of the rusty car within the main warehouse

The ones that don't increase special give you a bonus to stats example Energy Weapons Bobble head gives 25% more crit damage with Energy weapons

Comment: Perhaps you could list where the other bobble heads are? OP mentions the assumption of there being a bobblehead per stat, but is asking for **all** bobble head locations

Answer (score 10):

I've been working on this map for a few days now - all 20 Bobbleheads are marked on it. The above link will directly show only the Bobblehead markers.

[[image: Bobblehead Locations Map]]

http://www.fallout4map.com/?category=4

Like @Nightmare mentioned, they don't all increase SPECIAL, some of them give bonuses to stats.

Comment: nice map, tyvm!

Comment: may I ask how this does not constitute a "link only" answer?

Answer (score 0):

One Perception Bobblehead can be found in Concord's Museum of Freedom. When you meet Preston (the Minuteman), look at the desk with the broken computer on it.

Also, keep in mind that in Sanctuary you can find the SPECIAL book which allows you to pick one of the SPECIAL stats to increase by 1.